# WTSEnumerateProcesses vs CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

Tags: winapi, process, enumerate

I want to enumerate all running processes on a 32 or 64 (local) machine. What should I better use: WTSEnumerateProcesses or CreateToolhelp32Snapshot?

Comment: If you want to enumerate *all* processes then you shouldn't use WTSEnumerateProcesses().  That only enumerates the processes that are owned by the specific terminal server whose handle you pass.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I believe that argument is for remote servers, not per TS session on the local machine

Answer (score 2):

I would say CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, it works on any windows version except NT4 out of the box. On WinXP, WTSEnumerateProcesses only works when the terminal server service is running (And when it is running, WTSEnumerateProcesses will give you information about processes you are not supposed to have when running as non-admin, this hole was closed in Vista)

But the two functions don't give you the same information so it depends on what you are after, under the hood they both just call the semi documented [ZwQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Getting the full path of a proccess is problematic either way (GetModuleFileNameEx fails for WOW64, GetProcessImageFileName returns kernel path and has rename issues and QueryFullProcessImageName is Vista+ and has space in path issues supposedly)

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName() has space in path issues? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @raymai97 not 6 years later but https://web.archive.org/web/20120418075732/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684919(v=vs.85).aspx does have it in the comments as a 2008 server issue